# How to get times from a number of slots

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, calendar

I'm trying to get times of available slots. I have `startDateTime`, `endDateTime`, `duration`, and `bufferBetweenSlots` fields in my db. with some calculations I have figured out number of available slots.

the value of fields are:

```
startDateTime: 8/20/2021 11:30 AM
endDateTime: 8/20/2021 9:30 PM
duration: 60
bufferBetweenSlots: 30
```

but I'm not sure how to get the start and end time for the available slots. e.g. `10:00 - 11:00`

```
const getTimeDiffInMins = (endTime, startTime) =>
  (+new Date(endTime) - +new Date(startTime)) / (60 * 1000);

const getMultipleTimeSlots = (data) => {
  const diff = getTimeDiffInMins(data.end_date_time, data.start_date_time);
  const totalSlots = diff / data.duration;
  const totalBuffer = data.buffer_between_slots * totalSlots;
  const availableSlots = (diff - totalBuffer) / 60;

  return availableSlots;
};
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please explain more what is exactly the issue you have

Comment: There's no error. so after the calculation I get 5 available time slots. I'm wondering how can I get time of those 5 slots. like what is the time for each slot e.g. `10:00 - 11:00` just the timestamp or date would work I can then format it with momentjs

Comment: You should only need a buffer between slots, so the number of buffers is the number of slots less 1. You want to solve `n * slotTime + (n - 1) * buffer time == totalTime` such that `totalTime <= diff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need a buffer between slots, so the number of buffers is one less than the number of slots, i.e. you want to solve:

```
n * slotTime + (n - 1) * bufferTime == totalTime
```

such that:

```
totalTime <= diff
```

You can do that by adding the buffer to *totalTime* and dividing by `slotTime + bufferTime`, then flooring the result to get the whole number of available slots plus buffers. Then you can just iterate to produce the required start and end time. E.g.

```js
let startDateTime = new Date(2021,7,8,11,30); // 20 Aug 2021 11:30
let endDateTime =  new Date(2021,7,8,22);  // 20 Aug 2021 22:00
let duration = 60; // minutes
let bufferBetweenSlots = 30; // minutes

let diff = (endDateTime - startDateTime) / 6e4; // minutes
let numberOfSlots = Math.floor((diff + bufferBetweenSlots) / (duration + bufferBetweenSlots)); // minutes

let slots = [];
let time = new Date(startDateTime);
for (let i = 0; i < numberOfSlots; i++) {
  // Add the slot start time
  slots[i] = {start: time.toString()};
  // Increment time to end of slot
  time.setMinutes(time.getMinutes() + duration);
  // Add the end time
  slots[i].end = time.toString();
  // Increment time to end of buffer
  time.setMinutes(time.getMinutes() + bufferBetweenSlots);
}

console.log(slots);
```

I changed the end time to 22:00 to show it only puts in full slots. Whether you push timestamps or Date objects into the *slots* array is up to you. Just remember, if adding dates, to copy the date like:

```
slots[i] = {start: new Date(+time)};
...
slots[i].end = new Date(+time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @RobG for taking the time to answer. here's how I managed to slove it.

```js
const getTimeDiffInMins = (endTime, startTime) =>
  (+new Date(endTime) - +new Date(startTime)) / (60 * 1000);

const convertToMilliSecs = (value) => value * 60 * 1000;

// coming from the db
const data = {
  duration: 60,
  buffer_between_slots: 30,
  start_date_time: '2021-08-20T10:30:00Z',
  end_date_time: '2021-08-20T20:30:00Z',
};

const {
  duration: a,
  buffer_between_slots: b,
  end_date_time: x,
  start_date_time: y,
} = data;

const duration = getTimeDiffInMins(x, y);
const slotDuration = a;
const totalSlots = a + b;

const numberOfSlots = Math.floor(duration / totalSlots);

const slotsAvailable = [...Array(numberOfSlots).keys()].map((slotNumber) => {
  const slotStart = (slotNumber - 1) * totalSlots;
  const slotEnd = slotStart + slotDuration;

  return {
    start: +new Date(y) + convertToMilliSecs(slotStart),
    end: +new Date(y) + convertToMilliSecs(slotEnd),
  };
});

/*
  Now we can format the time however we want
  I'm using momentjs:
  moment(new Date(slot.start)).format('h:mma')
*/
console.log(slotsAvailable);
```